# Nunjucks if with more than one 'or' conditions

Tags: nunjucks

I'm kind of stuck making a multiple comparison using nunjucks!

It works when I use:

`{% if (tab.type != 'default') %}`

but not when I use:

`{% if (tab.type != 'placement') or (tab.type != "version1") or (tab.type != 'default') %}`

In the latter, it keeps getting there as if everything was equal instead of different!

HELP!
Thanks

Comment: Check that `tab.type` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Strange! I've had the exact same problem just now. To be precise, I was checking to see if page title is **not** certain value and then output some code. There were two pages which are impacted by this so my first logical condition was as same as yours.

```
{% if title != 'Messenger' or title != 'Video' %}
  OUTPUT
{% endif %}
```

It didn't work.

What worked for my case in the end (after countless combinations) is this:

```
{% if title != 'Messenger' and title !='Video' %}
  OUTPUT
{% endif %}
```

In my case it doesn't matter too much because I can have only one page title anyway, but in your or someone else's case it may be different. Someone maybe wants to trigger the output if **either** one of the conditions has been met.

As far as my logics goes: `and` means that **both** conditions must be fulfilled, which clearly isn't the case here.

If you still read this, please let me know if this has worked for you.

Comment: Hey! According to my logic, `and` means exactly the same as yours, **all** (in my case I had 3 conditions) must be true for the OUTPUT to work.  However, it seems that in Nunjucks works differently as your approach still worked, even if only one condition is met.